# How to use libreoffice writer in simdock

Tags: libreoffice

i am new at ubuntu and i have installed simdock, and when i use edit in simdock in run command i tried enter:

soffice.bin

and this was for to make it run libreoffice writer, and my question is what to write in to edit to make it run, and i tryied sevel times that could make the icon display but not run libreoffice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know entirely what Simdock is, but if it's trying to open LibreOffice by running soffice.bin, I'm not surprised that doesn't work, since the binary is called `libreoffice` ;).